# Using a tuple from df.itertuples(), how can I retrieve column values for each tuple element under a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` such as:

```
   1  2  3
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
```

Which has been created from a set containing relations such as:

```
{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}
```

I am trying to make the equivalence classes for this. Something like this:

```
[1] = {1}
[2] = {2}
[3] = {3}
```

I have done the following so far:

```
testGenerator = generatorTest(matrix)
indexCount = 1
while True:
    classRelation, loopCount = [], 1
    iterable = next(testGenerator)
    for i in iterable[1:]:
        if i == 1:
            classRelation.append(loopCount)
        loopCount += 1
    print ("[",indexCount,"] = ",set(classRelation))
    indexCount += 1
```

Which as you can see is very messy. But I do get more or less desired output:

```
[ 1 ] =  {1}
[ 2 ] =  {2}
[ 3 ] =  {3}
```

How can I accomplish the same output, in a tidier and more pythonic fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(3, dtype=int), [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

**`numpy.where`**

```
i, j = np.where(df.values == 1)
list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[j]))

[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

**`stack` and `compress`**

```
s = df.stack()
s.compress(s.astype(bool)).index.tolist()

[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) like:

**Code:**

```
df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

**Test code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
                  columns=[1, 2, 3], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
print(df.idxmax(axis=1))
```

**Results:**

```
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding one way. Let's say one of the rows has multiple `1`. The result will only return the position of the first `1`, rather than all of them, for instance.

Comment: We tend to get very literal with sample sets.  If the other answer does not meet your needs, you might consider expanding your sample.